# TypeError: unhashable type: 'peticion' python

Tags: python, poo, bucle-for, wireshark

Estoy haciendo un programa para analizar tramas de un esnifado de red a partir de un archivo exportado de Wireshark. La función en la que estoy trabajando ahora mismo lee el archivo con el objetivo de hacer un recuento de las peticiones diferentes que contiene y cuantas veces se repite cada una.

De modo que un registro contendría los campos "IP origen","IP Destino","Protocolo","Nº"

El problema, es que lo estoy haciendo en python y soy un completo noob.

La descripción lógica de la idea, es que un bucle recorre el archivo y por cada linea genera un objeto de tipo **peticion**.

Acto seguido el programa mira si esa petición, que vamos a llamar **p**, esta en una lista llamada peticiones.

Si es así, pasa a la siguiente linea del archivo. Si no, abre otro bucle que recorre las lineas del archivo, de nuevo creando un objeto por cada linea.

El bucle compara cada objeto creado, que llamaremos **c** con el objeto **p**, y si son iguales suma 1 al numero de repeticiones del objeto p.

Cuando el bucle ha recorrido todo el fichero se añade **p** con su recuento de repeticiones a la lista de peticiones.

Durante el siguiente recorrido el programa ignorara las lineas que sean iguales a la que hemos guardado, ya que esta en la lista.

El caso es que en el primer bucle me salta este error:

> File "D:\Utiles\Scripts\FuncPet.py", line 18, in petAglom
> if p in lista:
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'peticion'

He buscado información al respecto y he visto que para recorrer una lista esta tiene que tener un formato "clave-valor" y que la clave sea inmutable, o algo así. Según lo que he visto me da este error por que la clase set() es mutable.

La cosa es que no se si lo he entendido bien, y aun que así sea no se que tendría que cambiar para solucionarlo.

Aquí dejo el código:

FuncPEt.py (archivo con las funciones relacionadas con las peticiones aglomeradas):

```
import sys
from .peticionesClass import peticion

def petAglom(archivo):
    lista = set()
    non_interested = ["ARP", "Protocol"]

    with open(archivo) as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            try:
                partes = line.split(",")
                source = partes[2][1:-1]
                destination = partes[3][1:-1]
                protocol = partes[4][1:-1]
                info = partes[6][1:-1]
                if protocol not in non_interested:
                    p = peticion(source,destination,protocol)
               -----if p in lista:-------
                        pass
                    else:
                        for line in file.readlines():
                            try:
                                prts = line.split(",")
                                src = prts[2][1:-1]
                                dst = prts[3][1:-1]
                                prtcl = prts[4][1:-1]
                                inf = prts[6][1:-1]

                                if prtcl not in non_interested:
                                    c=peticion(src,dst,prtcl)
                                    if c == p:
                                        p.NoTimes += 1

                            except ValueError:
                                # Ignoramos cualquier error generado por split
                                pass
                        lista.add(p)

            except ValueError:
                # Ignoramos cualquier error generado por split
                pass
    
    return lista


def printPetAglom(archivo):
    lista = petAglom(archivo)
    print('"Origen","Destino","Protocolo","Nº"')
    for pet in lista:
        print(pet)

def savePetAglom(archivo):
    lista = petAglom(archivo)
    with open("PeticionesAglomeradas.csv","w") as f:
        f.write('"Origen","Destino","Protocolo","Nº"'+ '\n')
        for pet in lista:
            f.write(print(pet)+'\n')
        
    print('Hecho.')
```

La linea que esta entre ---guiones--- Es la que me dispara el error ahora mismo

peticionesClass.py:

```
class peticion():
    srcIP = ""
    dstIP = ""
    prtcl = ""
    info = ""
    NoTimes = 0

    def __init__(self,src,dst,prt):
        self.srcIP=src
        self.dstIP=dst
        self.prtcl=prt


    def __str__(self):
        return f'"{self.srcIP}","{self.dstIP}","{self.prtcl}","{self.NoTimes}"'


    def __eq__(self,peticion):
        if self.srcIP == peticion.srcIP and self.dstIP == peticion.dstIP and self.prtcl == peticion.prtcl:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es agregar el métido **hash** en la clase petición,

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.srcIP, self.dstIP, self.prtcl))
```

Al definirlo ya evalúa la condición correctamente.

Comment: Efectivamente el código pordría solucionar el problema, pero puedes indicar por que es una solución y dónde agregar este código? Recuerda que las respuestas que son solo código se marcan automáticamente como de baja calidad y entran en las colas de revisión. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.